# C# DataTable LINQ & GROUP BY

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, .net-3.5

I have a `DataTable` with 20 columns (I only need 3 of them.) I need to perform the following query on it and then save the results as an `array`. I've done some searching, but I can't figure out how to perform the mathematical operation. I know LINQ should be used, but I'm not getting anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated!

`SELECT DISTINCT columnZ, (columnX + columnY) / 2 FROM DataTable`

*EDIT - corrected SQL statement

Comment: How's that meant to work? When you group by columnZ, your select clause can not include non-aggregating function depending on columns other than columnZ itself. Can you explain us the broader problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Group-by is an aggregating function; you would need to take something like a sum,min,max etc for that to make sense.

Comment: Okay, how about this:

SELECT DISTINCT columnZ, (columnX + columnY) / 2
FROM DataTable

I only want to send the second column to an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your last comment (I suggest you update the question):

```
  var result = 
    (from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
     let average = ((double)row["columnX"] + (double)row["columnY"])/2
     select new 
     {
        ColumnZ = (string)row["columnZ"],
        Average = average
     }).Distinct();
```

Use your actual data types.